# "Could not inspect the application package". When i add any pod to my workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I Created an xcode project and signed with `Auto-Sign in` feature. Now i wanted to add a pod to my project, so i did `pod init` and added pod name `pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'` to it. then i did `pod install`. Now when i try to run the app builds successfully but showing error `Unable to install "BLE *******"`.

When i go to details its showing

Details

```
Unable to install "BLE ******"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653103
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653103
Failure Reason: Could not inspect the application package.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001213506e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121350de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012139056a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001085c4c12 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121390301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000121218a25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001086f5e7a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001086f7552 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff64422583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6442350e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff64428ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff64429452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff64432a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff646826fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff64681827 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

`NOTE:` I Dont have any non latin characters in my project name.

this is how my pod file looks like.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BLE ******' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

  # Pods for BLE ******

end
```

If i remove the pods then run the application, its running successfully. Help me out of this.

Versions im using:

Xcode: 11.3.1
swift: 5
pod: 1.9.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: After you added pods, did you close the project and open the newly created `xcworkspace`?

Comment: Yes, i did @zaitsman

Comment: Does the app run on the simulator?

Comment: No i added some third party framework related to core bluetooth. its failing to run on simulator with error undefined symbol @zaitsman

Comment: so that is your problem. Please post that simulator error, please

Comment: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MinewHTSensor
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTPeripheral
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTPeripheral
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTCentralManager

Comment: The source code for the library you mentioned does not include `MTPeripheral` nor any dependencies like this, can you search your project folder using text search for `MTPeripheral` to see where that is coming form?

Comment: Because it seems to me you maybe had previously added this kit, and then did not remove it properly and now your project is confused, as those types come from there: https://docs.beaconyun.com/iOS/iOS_BeaconPlus_Software_Development_Kit_Guide.html#design-instructions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219389/discussion-between-ravi-and-zaitsman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Added  `:linkage => :static` after `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`. This fixed my problem.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BLE ******' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static //-----> Here

pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

  # Pods for BLE ******

end
```

But i want to if there is any consequences for this?